# Load relative path of images instead of <?php echo $img ?>

Tags: php, timthumb

The timthumb function is not working after the security setting of web server is raised.
Images with "http://...." in URL are blocked.

I have found that `<?php echo $img ?>` was used to load the image. 
Original code:

```
<img src="<?php bloginfo('template_directory'); ?>/scripts/timthumb.php?h=100&amp;w=100&amp;zc=1&amp;src=<?php echo $img ?>" alt="<?php the_title_attribute(); ?>" width="100" height="100" />
```

Would someone please tell me how can I modify the code so that instead of

```
http://domain.com/wp-content/themes/a/scripts/timthumb.php?h=100&w=100&zc=1&src=http://domain.com/wp-content/uploads/thumbnail.jpg
```

the image URL will be

```
http://domain.com/wp-content/themes/a/scripts/timthumb.php?h=100&w=100&zc=1&src=../wp-content/uploads/2013/10/thumbnail.jpg
```

?

The code inside timthumb.php is super long. I will post the code if it's needed.

I know almost nothing about php code and only use plugins to build Wordpress websites. 
You would have save my life. Thank you very very much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends on where it is getting $img value from. If this is just a field on your article (through the extra parameters on the bottom), you could simply alter the url in your post. Alternatively, you could process the path, stripping out the http://domain.com/ and replace it with ../,

a la:

`$img = str_replace("http://domain.com/", "../", $img)`;

just before echoing it out on to the page.

Comment: You have saved my life @Gopherkhan !!! It just works like magic.
<br/>This is the modified code:<br/>
`<img src="<?php bloginfo('template_directory'); ?>/scripts/timthumb.php?h=100&amp;w=100&amp;zc=1&amp;src=<?php $img = str_replace("http://domain.com/", "../", $img)?><?php echo $img ?>" alt="<?php the_title_attribute(); ?>" width="100" height="100" />`